# AppCompatEditText is not shown

Tags: android

I have created a custom EditText to prevent pressing Enter (new line) in my input field. This is the class:

```
public class MyTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyTextView(Context context,
                  AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        // Just ignore the [Enter] key
        return true;
    }
    // Handle all other keys in the default way
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

First I extended the EditText class and it was working fine, but there was a warning to use AppCompatEditText instead (which extends EditText) . Now it doesn't appear. I've tried to enable, etc, but nothing seems to work. Anyone got an idea about this?

Bonus question: what about the Liskov substitution principle?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show layout file.